# Method to make a new twisted reactor?

Tags: python, twisted

I am making a IRC Log Bot which saves thel logs datewise. I want the program to close the present reactor and make a new one ( this is because, it will save the logs in a new file). I wrote a sample program but it is unable to work-

```
def event():
   if no date_change:
       do normal work that has to be done
   else:
       stop present reactor
       make a new reactor
```

Here is the actual code that I am using:-

```
def irc_NICK(self, prefix, params):
        """Called when an IRC user changes their nickname."""
        old_nick = prefix.split('!')[0]
        new_nick = params[0]
        if self.factory.filename.find(file_name_gen())!=-1:
                self.logger.log("<em>%s is now known as %s</em>" % (old_nick, new_nick),1)
        else:
                print "new itng"
                reactor.stop()
                irc.IRCClient.connectionLost(self, "Day Change")
                #earlier the LogBotFactory object is f 
                f1 = LogBotFactory("meeting-test", file_name_gen())
                reactor.connectTCP("irc.freenode.net", 6667, f1)
                reactor.run()
```

The second LogBotFactory object gets created but, the program stops due to some Unhandled error.
This is the traceback that I am getting...

```
1971-01-02 23:59:41+0530 [-] Log opened.
1971-01-02 23:59:41+0530 [-] Starting factory <__main__.LogBotFactory instance at 0x27318c0>
1971-01-03 00:00:10+0530 [LogBot,client] new itng
1971-01-03 00:00:10+0530 [LogBot,client] Starting factory <__main__.LogBotFactory instance at 0x2989cb0>
1971-01-03 00:00:10+0530 [LogBot,client] Unhandled Error
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/tcp.py", line 221, in _dataReceived
        rval = self.protocol.dataReceived(data)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/words/protocols/irc.py", line 2412, in dataReceived
        basic.LineReceiver.dataReceived(self, data.replace('\r', ''))
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/protocols/basic.py", line 581, in dataReceived
        why = self.lineReceived(line)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/words/protocols/irc.py", line 2420, in lineReceived
        self.handleCommand(command, prefix, params)
    --- <exception caught here> ---
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/words/protocols/irc.py", line 2464, in handleCommand
        method(prefix, params)
      File "irc.py", line 141, in irc_NICK
        reactor.run()
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 1191, in run
        self.startRunning(installSignalHandlers=installSignalHandlers)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 1171, in startRunning
        ReactorBase.startRunning(self)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 681, in startRunning
        raise error.ReactorAlreadyRunning()
    twisted.internet.error.ReactorAlreadyRunning: 

1971-01-03 00:00:10+0530 [-] Main loop terminated.
```

I am new to python twisted.
Please help, Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
print "new itng"
reactor.stop()
irc.IRCClient.connectionLost(self, "Day Change")
#earlier the LogBotFactory object is f 
f1 = LogBotFactory("meeting-test", file_name_gen())
reactor.connectTCP("irc.freenode.net", 6667, f1)
reactor.run()
```

This problem is even easier to solve than you think.  Delete the lines `reactor.stop()` and `reactor.run()` and you'll be all set.  In other words, just leave the reactor running.

Separately, you also need to replace the line `irc.IRCClient.connectionLost(self, "Day Change")` with `self.loseConnection()`.  Calling `connectionLost` does not close the connection.  It *gets* called when Twisted sees the connection has been closed.  If you call it yourself, your program might think the connection has been closed but it won't *really* have been closed - and after this happens enough times you'll be out of resources and your program won't work anymore.

You should only stop the reactor when you're done using Twisted (usually right before your program exits).

Comment: +1 for "Delete the lines reactor.stop() and reactor.run() and you'll be all set"